# "Could not compute output" error using tf.keras merge layers in Tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm trying to use a merge layer in tf.keras but getting `AssertionError: Could not compute output Tensor("concatenate_3/Identity:0", shape=(None, 10, 8), dtype=float32)`. Minimal (not)working example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

context_length = 10 

input_a = tf.keras.layers.Input((context_length, 4))
input_b = tf.keras.layers.Input((context_length, 4))

#output = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([input_a, input_b]) # same error
output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([input_a, input_b])

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = (input_a, input_b), outputs = output)

a = np.random.rand(3, context_length, 4).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(3, context_length, 4).astype(np.float32)

pred = model(a, b)
```

I get the same error with other merge layers (e.g. `add`). I'm on TF2.0.0-alpha0 but get the same with 2.0.0-beta1 on colab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok well the error message was not helpful but I eventually stumbled upon the solution: the input to `model` needs to be an iterable of tensors, i.e.

```
pred = model((a, b))
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because of the `tf.keras.layers.Input`. Tensorflow can't validate the shape of the layer thus it fails. This will work:

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.concat = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()
        # You can also add the other layers
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)

    def call(self, a, b):
        out_concat = self.concat([a, b])
        out_dense = self.dense_1(out_concat)

model = MyModel()

a = np.random.rand(3, 5, 4).astype(np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(3, 5, 4).astype(np.float32)

output = model(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks. Agreed this works but how do I construct a keras.Model to train if I use this approach? I can't pass (a,b) as `inputs` (also I want the batch_size to be variable in practice).

Comment: Surprised there's not a way to do what I want with the functional API (which I prefer just because the layers are defined where they're used and don't need naming) but this is a valid solution so I've accepted it. Thanks!